# Can you change utm_campaign based on an if statement?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, google-analytics

What I'm trying to do is send dynamic content based on if statements, however, I want to track this in google analytics.

To change utm_campaign, would it be some like this? It doesn't seem to be working.

```
%%[ IF (Gender == 'F') THEN]%% 
%%[ utm_campaign = 20180615_DynamicContentTest_Female ]%% 
%%[ ENDIF ]%% 
%%[ IF (Gender == 'M') THEN]%% 
%%[ utm_campaign = 20180615_DynamicContentTest_Male ]%% 
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a 'SET' statement .

I would also Rewrite the Ampscript block:

```
%%[ 
IF (Gender == 'F') 
    THEN 
        SET @utm_campaign = "20180615_DynamicContentTest_Female" 
ELSEIF (Gender == 'M') 
    THEN
        SET @utm_campaign = "20180615_DynamicContentTest_Male"
ENDIF 
]%%
```

Comment: Hey Data, thanks but I'm getting an error reading:

The variable name is not a valid because it is of zero length. Variable names must begin with the @ symbol followed by one or more letters, numbers, or underscores.
 Variable Name:

Comment: It need to be @utm_campaign include the @